# ngResource resourceProvider error with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Folowing the angular railscasts tutorial I have a rails app with angularjs-rails, 
both angular.js and angular-resource.js are being included in the head of my html file.

my welcome#index.html.erb is:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>


<div id="search" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="search()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newSearch.postcode">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>

  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="trader in traders">
    {{trader.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and my welcome.js.coffee:

```
app = angular.module("Search", ["ngResource"])

@SearchCtrl = ($scope, $resource) ->

  $scope.traders = [
    {name: "Jonlee"}
    {name: "Johnny"}
  ]

  $scope.search = ->
    console.log($scope.newSearch.postcode)
```

For some reason the resource is not working, I am receiving the below error:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource
```

Have googled around and have seen this error but in much more complicated examples that don't really fit this problem.

Application.js:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require_tree .
```

Exported welcome.js:

```
(function() {
  var app;

  app = angular.module("Search", ["ngResource"]);

  this.SearchCtrl = function($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.traders = [
      {
        name: "Jonlee"
      }, {
        name: "Johnny"
      }
    ];
    return $scope.search = function() {
      return console.log($scope.newSearch.postcode);
    };
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Where is `welcome.js.coffee` loaded in reference to `ngResource`?

Comment: All assets are loaded from /assets by Rails

Comment: Can you provide what the `application.js` file looks like?

Comment: Have you set `ng-app` somewhere in your layout view file? Probably unrelated but worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah it's set at the application.html.erb level and I have had angular working with mon-resource functionality so it was working. Reset Web server hasn't helped either.

Comment: Does the error disappear when you remove `$resource` from the arguments of the `SearchCtrl`?

Comment: Yeah it's that line causing the error message

Comment: I feel silly for suggesting this since I don't know coffeescript well but can you try to rewrite the code in javascript and make sure that the controller is directly hooked into the `app` variable you created. Maybe it already is, I just don't know. Clearly, I'm running out of ideas haha.

Comment: Okay, added the evaluated js file now =)